# Store sourceMap bundle.js.map file on a specific location with TerserWebpackPlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps, terser

What I want?

Store sourceMap `something.js.map` file to a specific location using TerserPlugin.
I've found some basic instructions on how to customize minification - https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin#custom-minify-function, but I can't make use of it.

Here's my optimization object from webpack.config.ts:

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: ifProduction({
    chunks: 'all',
    automaticNameDelimiter: '.'
  }, false),
  runtimeChunk: ifProduction(true, false),
  minimize: true,
  minimizer: [
    ifProduction(new TerserPlugin({
      parallel: true,
      sourceMap: true,
      minify: 'see value below -->>',
      terserOptions: {
        output: {
          ascii_only: true,
          beautify: false
        },
        compress: {
          pure_getters: true,
          join_vars: false
        }
      }
    }))
  ]
}
```

And here's my minify function, but I simply can't find a way to 'export' the .js.map. or don't understand how it works.

```
minify: (file, sourceMap) => {
    // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#minify-options
    const uglifyJsOptions: any = {
        /* your `uglify-js` package options */
    };

    if (sourceMap) {
        uglifyJsOptions.sourceMap = {
            content: sourceMap,
            root: "http://localhost:7000",
            url: "out.js.map"
        };
    }

    return require('uglify-js').minify(file, uglifyJsOptions);
}
```

`devtool: ifNotTest(ifDevelopment('eval', 'source-map'))`

I've spent two days trying to figure out how minify function works and question myself why they still refer to `uglify-js`. I thought that terser could have some options to customize sourceMap, but webpack's docs aren't useful that much for this case:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#minify

Answer (score 0):

You can use the webpack output setting "sourceMapFilename" to specify sourcemap file name and location.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputsourcemapfilename

Example:

```
        output: {
           filename: 'assets/js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
           chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
           sourceMapFilename: 'assets/js/maps/[name].[chunkhash].js.map'
        }
```